# Hover changes all my li tags

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists

I have this code, It's just a simple list to make a menu

```css
ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #212;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 29%;
  margin: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  -ms-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  -o-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  -ms-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  -o-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
}
ul li:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px white;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <a href="#">
    <li>MENU</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>CARDS</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>CONTACT</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

This creates the effect I want on my menu buttons, but for some reason the `padding-top` and `font-size` parts apply to all `li`, not just the one I `hover` over.

If I remove that two, the `box-shadow`, and relative positioning will only affect the hovered object.

How can I make it only affect the button I hover over?

I know I could give each button an ID and use `ID:hover`, but isn't there a shorter code solution?

Comment: could you show your html as well? or even better, a fiddle.

Comment: give your html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is **invalid**, you can only have `li` as direct child of `ul`

Change that and remove everything from `:hover` rule except `font-size` and `box-shadow` (exactly those you were only removing) and apply the `padding` you had in `li` to `a`

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #212;
  float: left;
  width: 29%;
  margin: 1% 1% 0;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0
}
ul li a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center
}
ul li:hover a {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">MENU</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">CARDS</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The way I wrote it works too. I wanted to wrap my <li> in an <a> so the whole button can be clicked. the way you wrote it the user have to click on word "MENU".

Comment: have you tested my snippet?? Just hover the `li` in every place, it works even in the black background... that's why changed your `box-shadow` to red, to even reinforce that. your **HTML IS INVALID**

Comment: Yea, it works, but which line makes the whole li, the whole button a link? When i tried without your CSS only the text inside was link

Comment: It is in my answer... padding in the `a` plus `display: block `

Comment: Just one more question, why is my HTML invalid? What does that mean? My browser could manage my code, but I guess it just auto-fixed it.

Comment: Im on the cell but iHTML invalid meaning won't pass the W3C validator and if you're using ul is mandatory to use li as direct child

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your ul li in a div and give that div a class. Then target that div's ul li.

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>MENU</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>CARDS</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu ul li:hover {
    position: relative;
    top: 55px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #212;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 29%;
    margin: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    -ms-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    -o-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    -ms-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    -o-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
}
```

Or target the a

```
.menu ul a li:hover {/* your css */}
```

Comment: The problem is with the hover, I have that ul li:hover code, and for some reason the font size applies to the "not active" li as well. Interestingly, the box shadow or the positioning part only applies to the li i hover over.

Comment: the html  is still invalid

Answer (score 0):

first of all your HTML is wrong. `<li>` should be immediate child of `<ul> or <ol>` but you have `<a href="#"><li>MENU</li></a>` this. second, you can target the hover element like this  `ul > li:hover{enter your styles here}` and here `ul li {}` use this style `ul li { vertical-align: top;}` because you are using `inline-block` so you need to use `vertical-align`

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vwvsz291/